# Attaching a form to each Post in a list of Posts

Tags: django, django-forms

So I have a List of Posts on my site and I would like to implement something like a "instant Comment". The Problem is that when I define a `Form` in the views.py and submit it, all Blogposts get the Comment. Something like `instance = get_object_or_404(Post,...)` or `instance = get_list_or_404(Post,...)` does not work. Then I tried to implement a `context_processor` for the form but same problem. Now I want to initialize a `API` to take care of the task but maybe someone has a better Idea on how to solve that issue and I don't have to try different things all the time.

my Blogpost are a normal `QuerySet` like `articles = Post.objects.all()` 
the form needs some information from the Post like `content_type` and `id`. If any other Informations are required leave a comment.

> Edit

in views.py

```
instance = get_object_or_404(Post,id=1)
initial_data = {
    "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
    "object_id": instance.id
}
formInCom = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
if formInCom.is_valid():
    print("form is valid")
    content_type = instance.get_content_type
    content_data = formInCom.cleaned_data.get("content")
    obj_id       = formInCom.cleaned_data.get("object_id")
    new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                user         = request.user,
                content_type = content_type,
                object_id    = obj_id,
                content      = content_data,
        )
    messages.success(request, 'comment was posted')
```

So I can Post comments like this, but for the Blogpost with the id of 1. Because of `instance = get_object_or_404(Post,id=1)` when I try to use it without `id` it does not work, changing `get_object_or_404` to `get_list_or_404` does not work. When I leave the initial Data out of the validation, the form is not valid. How to override the `id`?

> edit 2

forms.py for comment:

```
class CommentForm (forms.Form):
  content_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
  object_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
  content = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

in template:

```
<form method="POST" >
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ formInCom.content }}
 {{ formInCom.object_id }}
 {{ formInCom.content_type }}
  <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over-thinking this. You just need to include the post ID in the form you submit to create the comment.

Comment: Yeah I also have the feeling that I'm overthinking this but I cannot fetch the right ID. I added the context processor function. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you are using a context processor, for a start. But you need to show the template, to see where the value for object_id is coming from.

Comment: I edited the question and took the form validation back into views.py. the Value object.id is coming from the instance. That is where the Problem is, I cannot fetch the Object Post properly. If I do not declare an ID I get: `get method returned more than one object...` If I hardcode an ID I always get the same Post. Without declaring an instance, I cannot render the form...